# mySQL Error code 1136 with TRIGGER Syntax

Tags: mysql

I have homework that use TRIGGER Syntax with this code below

```
CREATE TABLE mahasiswa_log (
idLog INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
nim INT,
keterangan VARCHAR(30),
waktu TIMESTAMP
)ENGINE = INNODB;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER insert_log
AFTER INSERT ON mahasiswa 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO mahasiswa_log VALUES 
(new.nim, 'Ditambah', NOW());
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and after that, I tried to use that trigger in my code by making this code

```
INSERT INTO mahasiswa(nim, namaMahasiswa, idProdi, jenisKelamin, angkatan, asal) VALUES 
(160613,'Sieg', 8, 'Laki-laki', 2016, 'Manado');
```

But that `INSERT INTO` syntax wont work and it mentions that I have **Error Code 1136 : Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**.

After I tried to delete the TRIGGER Syntax using
`DROP TRIGGER insert_log`, the `INSERT INTO` Syntax can work properly, but I still wonder why the INSERT INTO Syntax wont work if the TRIGGER Syntax still exist

Already tried many ways and searching but still didn't know why my code has **Error Code 1136** that mentions **Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

Comment: The `mahasiswa_log` table has 4 columns, you're only providing 3 values.

Comment: owhh, so I have to add `NULL` in my TRIGGER columns even though it's using `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: Of course. You're allowed to insert specific values into an AUTO_INCREMENT column. If you want it to get the default you have to say so specifically.

Comment: okay, thanks a lot man. Really appreciate ur help

Comment: In general I recommend always listing the columns you're inserting into, rather than depending on the order of columns in the table.

Comment: yeah, I'll follow ur advice